# Definition of "uniformly regular" signals (as used in the book "Wavelet Tour of Signal Processing")

Tags: functional-analysis, signal-processing, wavelets

The author uses the term "uniformly regular" and I get the idea of it's meaning through the context, yet the phrase is used as if could also have a precise mathematical meaning.

Is there a definition of *uniformly regular* signals?

The first chapter and the preface are available at [the books website](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~peyre/wavelet-tour/)

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed not precisely formulated in the book. Anyway, here is what I can make of it: Regularity usually refers to the degree of differentiability. What degree it refers to is not of central interest to the author I think. The purpose of the formulation seems to be to give the reader an intuition of the meaning of decay of the Fourier Transform (high order of differentiability <-> fast decay of the Fourier coefficients).

I am quite sure there is no precise definition of a *uniformly regular signal*. The mathematical equivalent should be *continuously differentiable of a certain degree*.

Answer (score 1):

Notice in Chapter 1.2.1 of the book Wavelet Tour by S.Mallat, there is a sentence

> A linear approximation space $U_N$ corresponds to a uniform grid that approximates precisely uniformly regular signals.

We might guess that uniformly regularity means that the function is smooth in the sense that its frequency representation has support of up to first $N$ bases.